# After counting characters counter stuck?

Tags: c++, pointers, char, constants, increment

Hi guys I have the following code, I don't understand why in the function "strcount" the last line doesn't display the whole string once again?
Thanks in advance!

```
#include  <iostream>
const int ArSize = 10;
void strcount(const char * str);

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    char input[ArSize];
    char next;

    cout << "Enter a line:\n";
    cin.get(input, ArSize);
    while(cin)
    {
        cin.get(next);
        while(next != '\n')
            cin.get(next);
        strcount(input);
        cout << "Enter next line (empty line to quit):\n";
        cin.get(input, ArSize);
    }
    void strcount(const char * str)
    {
        using namespace std;
        static int total = 0;
        int count = 0;

        cout << "\"" << str <<"\" contains ";
        while(*str++)
            count++;
        total += count;
        cout << count << " characters\n";
        cout << total << " characters total\n" << endl;
        cout << str << endl;
    }
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Why would you expect `cout << str` to print the original string? You do realize you are modifying the `str` pointer in the `while` loop, right?

Comment: I recommend using `std::string` and `std::getline` for reading text from the User.  A lot easier than worrying about array overflows or missing the nul terminating character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function `strcount`

```
while(*str++)
```

increments `str` until you reach the end of the string.

Then trying to output

```
cout << str << endl;
```

will display nothing, as `str` now points to the end of the string.